# Xaml exception: "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception." wpf

Tags: wpf, exception, user-controls, staticresource

I am Trying to design a user control, but  When I try and build, it says "Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception. Error is at "BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:CustomButton}}""

Styles.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary>
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CustomControl">

    <Style x:Key="PrimaryButtonStyle" TargetType="controls:CustomButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type controls:CustomButton}}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="182"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40"/>

    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

MyUserControl.xaml

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Titan.SystrayPopupPlugin.Audio.Views.GenericAudioOsdView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:CustomControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>       
            <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,24,0,0">
                <controls:CustomButton Style="{DynamicResource SecondaryButtonStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```